# RSA random key generation

Tags: rsa, public-key, randomness, prime-numbers

How RSA keys are tested for primality if they are random generated? I imagine this could be time consuming task.

Comment: @kelalaka: The answer to the question originally linked as duplicate does not explain how the primality of the factors $p$ and $q$ is tested, other than by reference. E.g FIPS 186-5 appendix [B.3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A183%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C469%2C0%5D) or [A.1.4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A140%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C169%2C0%5D). I linked to another duplicate, and might make or improve an answer.

Comment: Not just time consuming, indeterminate runtime. Which can be fun if you have e.g. a smart card processor in a personalization machine inside of a credit card factory.